# Как передать кириллицу в VK API

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, urlencode

VK API не постит кириллицу:

```py
message_to_post = caption + "\n\n" + annotation
post_request_params = (
   ('owner_id', '-%d' % group_id),
   ('from_group', '1'),
   ('message', message_to_post),
   ('attachments', attachments),
   ('access_token', access_token),
   ('guid', id_news),
   ('version', 5.73)
)

post_response_raw = requests.get(
    'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post', 
    params=post_request_params
)
post_response = post_response_raw.json()
```

Я попробовал загуглить, но не понял, чего от меня хочет ВК и как перекодировать url?

ps в поддержке мне посоветовали пропустить `url` через `urlencode`, чтоб подтвердить, что я - живой пользователь.

Comment: `print(message_to_post)` нормально всё печатает?

Comment: да, в message_to_post кириллица

Comment: А если заменить requests.get на `requests.post(..., data=post_request_params)`?

Comment: ничего не изменилось